# ElasticSearch _Source is always empty on the return

Tags: elasticsearch

I am posting a query to `http://localhost:9200/movie_db/movie/_search` but _source attribute is always empty on the return resposne. I made it enabled but that doesn't help.

Movie DB:

```
TRY DELETE /movie_db
PUT /movie_db {"mappings": {"movie": {"properties": {"title": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "snowball"}, "actors": {"type": "string", "position_offset_gap" : 100, "analyzer": "standard"}, "genre": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}, "release_year": {"type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed"}, "description": {"_source": true, "type": "string", "analyzer": "snowball"}}}}}
BULK INDEX movie_db/movie
{"_id": 1, "title": "Hackers", "release_year": 1995, "genre": ["Action", "Crime", "Drama"], "actors": ["Johnny Lee Miller", "Angelina Jolie"], "description": "High-school age computer expert Zero Cool and his hacker friends take on an evil corporation's computer virus with their hacking skills."}
{"_id": 2, "title": "Johnny Mnemonic", "release": 1995, "genre": ["Science Fiction", "Action"], "actors": ["Keanu Reeves", "Dolph Lundgren"], "description": "A guy with a chip in his head shouts incomprehensibly about room service in this dystopian vision of our future."}
{"_id": 3, "title": "Swordfish", "release_year": 2001, "genre": ["Action", "Crime"], "actors": ["John Travolta", "Hugh Jackman", "Halle Berry"], "description": "A cast of characters challenge society's commonly held view that computer experts are not the beautiful people. Somehow, the CIA is hacked in under 5 minutes."}
{"_id": 4, "title": "Tomb Raider", "release_year": 2001, "genre": ["Adventure", "Action", "Fantasy"], "actors": ["Angelina Jolie", "Jon Voigt"], "description": "The story of a girl and her quest for antiquities in the face of adversity. This epic is adapter from its traditional video-game format to the big screen"}
```

Query:

```
{
    "query" : 
    {
        "term" : { "genre" : "Crime" }
    },
}
```

Results:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.30685282,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "movie_db",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.30685282,
                "_source": {}
            },
            {
                "_index": "movie_db",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.30685282,
                "_source": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your mapping and how do you index data ? It will help us to give you an answer. You can create a gist to keep the post short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In elasticsearch config folder, open elasticsearch.yml and set cluster.name to a different value, then restart elasticsearch.bat

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: despite enabling `_source` in my query as well as in my mappings, `_source` would always be `{}`.

Your proposed solution of setting cluster.name in elasticsearch.yml gave me the hint that the problem must be some hidden setting in the old cluster.

I found out that I had an index template definition that came with a plugin I installed (in my case elasticsearch-transport-couchbase), which said

```
    "_source" : {
      "includes" : [ "meta.*" ]
    },
```

thereby implicitely excluding all fields other than `meta.*` from source.

Check your templates like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/?pretty
```

I deleted the `couchbase` template like so

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_template/couchbase
```

and created a new, almost identical one but with `source` enabled.

Here is how:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

I once accidentally passed a single field in source array and that too didn't exist. Just for example `"_source": ["bazinga"]` and in the aggregations result `source` was empty.

So maybe you could simple pass a totally unrelated string into the `_source` array. This can be a better solution instead of making changes in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.